# Computation of real integrals using Cauchy's integral theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck at an exercise regarding the evaluation of real integrals via Cauchy's integral theorem.

> Consider the function $f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{z}$ along the curve given in the picture below. Use it to prove the following
> $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx= \frac{\pi}{2}, \ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)-e^{-x}}{x} dx=0$$
>
> [image]

In oder to solve this, I considered the curves

$$ \alpha: [0, \frac{\pi}{2}] \to \mathbb{C}, \alpha(t)= \varepsilon e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}-t)} \\
h_{\alpha}: [\varepsilon, R] \to \mathbb{C}, \ h_{\alpha}=t e^{i \cdot 0} \\
\beta: [0, \frac{\pi}{2}] \to \mathbb{C}, \ \beta(t)=Re^{it} \\
h_{\beta}: [\varepsilon, R] \to \mathbb{C}, \ h_{\alpha}=(R+\varepsilon-t) e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}}. $$

The four curves form a curve $\gamma$ that bounds the $C^1$-Image of a rectangle. So the Cauchy integral theorem gives

$$ 0=\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz=\int_{\alpha} f(z) dz+\int_{h_{\alpha}} f(z) dz+\int_{\beta} f(z) dz+\int_{h_{\beta}} f(z)  dz$$

or equivalently

$$ -\int_{\alpha} f(z) dz-\int_{\beta} f(z) dz=\int_{h_{\alpha}} f(z) dz+\int_{h_{\beta}} f(z) dz $$

I also know that

$$ 
2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x} dx=\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x} dx \\
2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx=\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx \\
\int_{0}^{c} \frac{\cos(x)}{x} dx=\text{Re}(\int_{0}^{c} \frac{e^{ix}}{x} dx) \\
\int_{0}^{c} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx=\text{Im}(\int_{0}^{c} \frac{e^{ix}}{x} dx)$$

But now I'm a bit lost at what to do next. I also do not see the link between $\frac{\cos(x)-e^{-x}}{x}$ and $f$ (save for the fact that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)-e^{-x}}{x} dx=\text{Re}(\int_{0}^{c} \frac{e^{ix}}{x} dx) -\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x} dx$).

Comment: Obviously, the next thing you need to figure out is what exactly $$\int_\alpha f(z)\,dz, \int_\beta f(z)\,dz, \int_{h_\alpha} f(z)\,dz, \int_{h_\beta} f(z)\,dz$$ look like as integrals in terms of $dt$, not $dz$. If you go ahead and express them that way, you will find the answers to at least some of your concerns.